# How to use openCV's SphericalWarper?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, 360-degrees

I have an equirectangular stitched panoramic image that I want to display with spherical projection. I was previously displaying the image as-is (with equirectangular projection) using openCV's `imshow`, but the top and bottom parts of the image are distorted (as with any equirectangular projection) and I want to get rid of this distortion.

I found [SphericalWarper](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d6/dd0/classcv_1_1detail_1_1SphericalWarper.html) in openCV that can possibly help me do this. But I'm having some problems understanding exactly how to use `warp`.

For now, the section of the my code that does warping looks like this:

```
    Mat panorama;
    Mat K = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_32F);
    Mat R = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32F);
    detail::SphericalWarper warper = detail::SphericalWarper(1.0f);
    warper.warp(imgBgr, K, R, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_DEFAULT,panorama);

    imshow("Display frame", panorama);
    waitKey(0);
```

My source image, `imgBgr` looks like this (not exactly mine, just an example):

[image]

Currently, the output image I get, `panorama`, looks like an image from an image sensor without any lens:

[image]

I guess this makes sense because currently my camera intrinsic matrix is a 3x3 matrix of all zeros. So my **question** is: What should the camera intrinsic matrix contain? I have camera intrinsic parameters for the cameras that took images that were stitched to produce my source equirectangular image (`imgBgr`), but I'm not sure if the `warper` needs these same parameters. I just want to view my source image with a spherical projection so that the distortion caused by equirectangular projection is not there anymore. I want the output image to be similar to what Google street-view looks like.

Comment: Image is a blue rectangle to me.

Comment: @Yakk If you're talking about the `panorama` image, yes that's how my output looks like currently.

Answer (score 2):

I stick in the same problem, but after some experiments got out of the hole. Intrinsics matrix looks like:

```
fx,  0, cx,
 0, fy, cy,
 0,  0,  1
```

where f(x,y) is scale factor, c(x,y) is center offset. You can play out with all of the parameters in code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// Calculates rotation matrix given euler angles.
Mat eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(Vec3f &theta)
{
    // Calculate rotation about x axis
    Mat R_x = (Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
               1,       0,              0,
               0,       cosf(theta[0]),   -sinf(theta[0]),
               0,       sinf(theta[0]),   cosf(theta[0])
               );

    // Calculate rotation about y axis
    Mat R_y = (Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
               cosf(theta[1]),    0,      sinf(theta[1]),
               0,               1,      0,
               -sinf(theta[1]),   0,      cosf(theta[1])
               );

    // Calculate rotation about z axis
    Mat R_z = (Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
               cosf(theta[2]),    -sinf(theta[2]),      0,
               sinf(theta[2]),    cosf(theta[2]),       0,
               0,               0,                  1);


    // Combined rotation matrix
    Mat R = R_z * R_y * R_x;

    return R;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";

    Mat origImg = imread("..path to file..");
    imshow("src", origImg);

    float scale = 100.0;
    float fx = 100, fy = 100, cx = 500, cy = 300;
    Vec3f rot = {};

    while (true) {
        cout << "•" << endl;
        cout << "Fx: " << fx << "; Fy: " << fy << endl;
        cout << "Cx: " << fx << "; Cy: " << fy << endl;
        cout << "Scale: " << scale << endl;
        cout << "Ang: " << rot << endl;

        detail::SphericalWarper wrap(scale);
        Mat K = (Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
                 fx, 0, cx,
                 0, fy, cy,
                 0, 0, 1);
        Mat R = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(rot);

        Mat dst;
        wrap.warp(origImg, K, R, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, dst);
        imshow("dst", dst);
        cout << dst.size() << endl;
        char c = waitKey();

        if (c == 'q') break;
        else if (c == 'a') fx += 10;
        else if (c == 'z') fx -= 10;
        else if (c == 's') fy += 10;
        else if (c == 'x') fy -= 10;
        else if (c == 'd') scale += 10;
        else if (c == 'c') scale -= 10;

        else if (c == 'f') rot[0] += 0.1;
        else if (c == 'v') rot[0] -= 0.1;
        else if (c == 'g') rot[1] += 0.1;
        else if (c == 'b') rot[1] -= 0.1;
        else if (c == 'h') rot[2] += 0.1;
        else if (c == 'n') rot[2] -= 0.1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```